# DrawText randomly gives error: Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have an error:

> Parameter is not valid.

This error occurs about 1 in 5 times.

The error occurs on this line:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(drawing, "Code12", font, fullWidthRectangle,
                                        textColor,
                                        flags);
```

**Small code example (not actual code):**

```
public Image CreateTripDetailPreview(Image image)
{
    using (var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection())
    using (var fontCollectionBold = new PrivateFontCollection())
    {
        fontCollection.AddFontFile("Assets\\SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
        fontCollectionBold.AddFontFile("Assets\\SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf");

        //This will be used to define heigt of text and allign text
        Rectangle fullWidthRectangle;

        var widthInDip = 360;
        var imgHeigtInDip = 168;
        var canvasWidth = 1080;
        var canvasHeight = 1200;
        var dip = canvasWidth / widthInDip;
        var leftRightMargin = 15 * dip;
        var resolutionScale = 5;

        using (Image img = new Bitmap(canvasWidth * resolutionScale, canvasHeight * resolutionScale))
         using (Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img))
         {
            //Clear 'background' and make it white
            drawing.Clear(Color.White);

            var imageHeight = (int)167.5 * dip;
            var height = imageHeight * resolutionScale;

            using (var cityImageBitmap = new Bitmap(image))
            using (var resizedCityImage = new Bitmap(cityImageBitmap, new Size(canvasWidth, imageHeight)))
            {
                canvasWidth *= resolutionScale;
                canvasHeight *= resolutionScale;
                dip *= resolutionScale;
                leftRightMargin *= resolutionScale;

                TextFormatFlags flags;
                using (var regularFont = new Font(fontCollection.Families[0], 1, FontStyle.Regular))
                using (var boldFont = new Font(fontCollectionBold.Families[0], 1, FontStyle.Regular)
                        ) //1 as default fontsize, fontsize will be calculated for each property
                {
                    Color textColor = Color.FromArgb(102, 102, 102);

                    //FlightCode
                    height += 4 * dip;
                    fullWidthRectangle = new Rectangle(leftRightMargin, height,
                    canvasWidth - leftRightMargin * 2,
                                    (int)22.5 * dip);
                    using (Font font = GetFontSizeByBox(drawing, "Code12",
                                    fullWidthRectangle.Size,
                                    regularFont))
                    {
                        flags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(drawing, "Code12", font, fullWidthRectangle,
                                        textColor,
                                        flags);
                    }

                    using (var result = new Bitmap(img, canvasWidth / resolutionScale, canvasHeight / resolutionScale))
                    using (Graphics drawing2 = Graphics.FromImage(result))
                    {
                        drawing2.DrawImage(resizedCityImage, new Point(0, 0));
                        return new Bitmap(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GetFontSizeByBox method:**

```
    private static Font GetFontSizeByBox(Graphics g, string longString, Size room, Font preferedFont, int extraSize = 0)
    {
        SizeF realSize = g.MeasureString(longString, preferedFont);
        var heightScaleRatio = room.Height / realSize.Height;
        var widthScaleRatio = room.Width / realSize.Width;
        var scaleRatio = heightScaleRatio < widthScaleRatio ? heightScaleRatio : widthScaleRatio;
        var scaleFontSize = preferedFont.Size * scaleRatio;
        return new Font(preferedFont.FontFamily, scaleFontSize + extraSize, preferedFont.Style);
    }
```

**Notes**

1. `GC.Collect()` at the top of this method fixes the problem, I do not wish to use this 'fix' as its better to prevent it.
2. Everything disposable is in using statements
3. The method works most of the time, 1/5 times it fails

**Values of DrawText when error occurs:**

- Graphics object (properties accessible)
- "Code12" regular string
- font `Name = "Source Sans Pro" Size=179.088287` (properties accessible)
- Rectangle `X = 225 Y = 2565 Width = 4950 Height = 330`
- Color `Name=ff666666, ARGB=(255, 102, 102, 102)`
- Flags `TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding`

If anyone know why I'm getting this error or how to fix it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the values of the arguments when calling `TextRenderer.DrawText`? What values do you get?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom They're always the same in the example (and it fails about 1/5 times) so its not likely its the values. I am going to check for you though

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Added the values

Comment: In the lines var imageHeight = (int)167.5 * dip; and canvasWidth - leftRightMargin * 2, (int)22.5 * dip); the cast only cast the values 167.5 and 22.5 to int's. Maybe you need to place brackets around the whole expression. eg var imageHieght = (int)(167.5 * dip). Just a thought.

Comment: @dannyhut the dip is a whole number already, good spotting thoug! WIll be cleaner in your way. Error remains sadly :(

Comment: FontCollection will be disposed of sometimes before it is used as there are no curry brackets around the following code in the line: using (var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection()), or am I missing something in how using works.

Comment: @dannyhut You can put 2 using statement under each other and make them "share" their brackets.

Comment: Deleting a question with helpful comments is not a very good strategy.  I told you that GC.Collect() would solve your problem.  I also told you that the bug is *not* located in the code that fails.  It is just the canary in the coal mine that keels over from the underlying problem.  I also told you to use Task Manager to look at the USER and GDI Object counts, what you observed should not be missing from the question.

Comment: @HansPassant I made a working example this time so people could test it. I added the User and GDI object counts in task manager and did not observe anything strange. The number goes up a bit when the method is running, then goes down just fine after. And we both know that `GC.Collect()` isn't a solution :). Btw the bug is located in the code I posted now as this is from a test project to reproduce the bug (which it does).

Comment: @HansPassant Oh and I changed my code up a lot to no longer have to call dispose and have using statements instead, error still persists so I made a new quesiton.

Comment: EpicKip when I have an issue look this, I split the code up into functions. I'd split this function up into 3 functions one for each element and 1 to call each function. Then just comment out each function until one errors. Errors don't always appear where the computer says they do.

Comment: @dannyhut I "found" the error. It seems garbage collection isnt appearing fast enough to clean up my disposed bitmaps etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, as Hans Passant said `GC.Collect();` at the top of the method will fix the problems. This did indeed work but I wanted to find out why.

The way the code is structured all the disposable objects will be disposed after the method is done (because of all the using statements), there is enough memory in a `32bit` application to run this method once or twice. But as soon as the method is called with some generations of garbage still present it would crash on making the bitmap.

**Solution:**
If you have this problem and you don't wan't to force garbage collection each time you run your method you can set a threshold like so:

```
if( Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64 > someNumber )
{
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Turns out this did not work for me as the threshold was hit every time, so I just settled with the `GC.Collect();` every time. If anyone has a better solution (not increasing memory) don't hesitate to post.

Comment: It seems strange that running short of memory doesn't cause the GC to fire anyway. I thought this was how it worked.

Comment: @dannyhut That's also how I thought (and the seniors here) it worked. But somehow that won't count for GDI creating bitmaps? I'm not sure, posted my findings because it might help someone ;)